# Split string with escaped delimeter using a delimeter

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, split

Is there any better way to split a string which contains escaped delimeter in it.

```
string = "fir\&st_part&secon\&d_part"
print(string.split('&'))
# is giving me
>>> ['fir\\', 'st_part', 'secon\\', 'd_part']
# but not
>>> ['fir&st_part', 'secon&d_part']
```

I have added an escape character `\` before `&`  in `fir&st_part` and `secon&d_part` with the intention that split function will escape the following character.

Is there any better way to do this if not by using a string split?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can user regular expression!

split if `?<!` current position of string is not preceded with backward (\, two slashes to escape it)slash and ampersand symbol(&)

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r'(?<!\\)&', string)
['fir\\&st_part', 'secon\\&d_part']
```

With the resulting list, you can iterate and replace the escaped '\&' with '&' if necessary!

```
>>> import re
>>> print [each.replace("\&","&") for each in re.split(r'(?<!\\)&', string)]
['fir&st_part', 'secon&d_part']
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible using a regular expression:

```
import re
string = "fir\&st_part&secon\&d_part"
re.split(r'[^\\]&', string)
# ['fir\\&st_par', 'secon\\&d_part']
```